# Asp.net search similar to Amazon

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, search, e-commerce

I am working on an e-commerce website and would like to implement a search which is similar to that of Amazon. I have read about Solr and even ElasticSearch, but I was wondering if I could find an alternative which isn't as complex as these two.

I have the following tables:

Categories, Brands and Products.

```
tblCategories
------------------------------
ID            Name        
1             Shoes
2             Watch Accessories



tblBrands
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ID            Name        
1             Puma
2             Nike


 tblProducts
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID           ProductName        BrandName         CategoryName 
1             Flip-Flop            Nike              Shoes
2           Running Shoes          Nike              Shoes
```

I want the search to be over all three of these tables.
I am using Asp.net C#.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys in each table or do you really only have CategoryName etc.? If you have foreign keys you could make inner joins and create a view of the joined table and therefore search over all of the three tables.

Comment: I do have foreign keys, the search needs to be similar to that of Amazon. I have a normal search functionality working